# Jenkins: how to I automatically restart a triggered build

Tags: jenkins, jenkins-plugins

I have one Jenkins job that triggers another job via "***Trigger/call builds on other projects.***"

The triggered downstream job sometimes fails due to environmental reasons. I'd like to be able to restart the triggered job multiple times until it passes.

More specifically, I have a job which does the following:

1. Triggers a downstream job to configure my test environment. This process is sensitive to environmental issues and may fail. I'd like this to restart multiple times over a period of about an hour or two until it succeeds.
2. Trigger another job to run tests in the configured environment. This should not restart multiple times because any failure here should be inspected.

I've tried using [Naginator](https://wiki.jenkins.io/display/JENKINS/Naginator+Plugin) for step 1 above (the configuration step). The triggered job does indeed re-run until it passes. Naginator looks so promising, but I'm disappointed to find that when the first execution of the job fails, the upstream job fails immediately despite a subsequent rebuild of the triggered job passing. I need the upstream job to block until the downstream set of jobs passes (or fails to pass) via Naginator.

Can someone help me know what my options are to accomplish this? Can I configure things differently for the upstream job so it relates to the Naginator-managed job better? I'm not wed to Naginator and am open to other plugins or options.

In case its helpful, my organization is currently using Jenkins 1.609.3 which is a few years old. I'd consider upgrading if that leads to a solution.